# Competing risk model with 0 standard error and 0 naive standard error

Tags: r, survival-analysis, weibull

I am fitting a competing risk model on a proprietary data set with correlated
data. The fit works but I get strange results for the std. error and the Naive
SE in my model summary. I was wondering whether anyone has faced similar
problems and knows how to solve it.

```
> summary(model)

 Call:
 survreg(formula = Surv(time, is_stop_code) ~ strata(code) + 
     cluster(id), data = data)
                       Value Std. Err (Naive SE)         z p
 (Intercept)          7.3726 9.89e-61   1.43e-32  7.45e+60 0
 a                    0.2009 0.00e+00   0.00e+00       Inf 0
 b                   -5.0211 0.00e+00   0.00e+00      -Inf 0
 c                   -2.3084 0.00e+00   0.00e+00      -Inf 0
 d                   -1.2342 0.00e+00   0.00e+00      -Inf 0
 e                 -169.9852 3.42e-61   5.42e-33 -4.97e+62 0
```

Comment: The issue has most likely to do with events with low frequency of occurrences. After removing codes that have less than 5 occurrences  or did not cause a stop the model gives non zero standard error and naive standard error and non infinite z.

Comment: Coefficient of 10 of greater or standard errors that are all effectively 0 are generally evidence of data "pathology". You should build some tables to investigate.

Comment: Could you elaborate?

Comment: Coefficients are the log relative hazard. Look at exp(-169). Since you haven't included any description of hte data it's a bit hard to know what the intercept refers to but it has a relative risk of exp(7.4) compared to `<something>`

Comment: Thanks, I found that the issue was caused by the optimization. Removing low occurrence events lead to more realistic values.

Comment: So this question should be closed or deleted?

Comment: I can close it. The issue was related to low frequency events. I think it would be valuable for people in the future.